# Sales order item details storage, which way to go?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, mysql

I'm working on a type of inventory management application using the following mixture or technologies: MySql, C#, WPF, ADO.Net EntityFramework 4.

I'm a little confused as to how I should store the details on the sales/purchase invoices in the database.

This is how I had it before... I stored the details in a LongText field as an XML string.

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| SalesInvoices                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| int InvoiceID: primary key, auto-incretement      |
| int OrderID                                       |
| int CustomerID                                    |
| int CreatedByEmployeeID                           |
| DateTime Date                                     |
| DateTime? ShippingDate                            |
| LongText ItemsData (details, stored as XML)       |
| LongText TransactionData (details, stored as XML) |
| Double Subtotal                                   |
| Double Tax                                        |
| Double Freight                                    |
| Double FreightTax                                 |
| Double Total                                      |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

However, I looked around on the web and most of the examples I've seen have a separate table `SalesInvoiceDetails`. So I'm wondering, is there something wrong with my approach, should I go through the trouble of switching over to the approach.

**My Requirements:** The search through the `SalesInvoice` table should be really fast. I do not need to search through the details of the invoice unless the user actually opens up an invoice, so It's okay if the user has to wait a second or two over here.

The reason I chose my approach the first time was because I thought millions of details in one table will eventually make it really slow to open and I would have to worry about deleting and updating rows if a user decides to go back to change something. And I thought it would be a bit of a hassle to have sub items for detail lines and storing them as rows and keeping track of the parent/children relationship and etc.

So yea, I'm wondering is there any good reason why I should abandon my approach and make another table for the details.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you've been working under the impression that parsing an XML string will be more performant than querying a relational database table. Please, please [read this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) for an excellent explanation of what's wrong with that misconception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you think using separate table would be slow? I think you need to read(If you haven't yet) about [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), [indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)) and so on to get good performance. To update detail now you need to transfer and insert whole blob instead of, for example one price field.

Also I found nice article [here](http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/). I realy liked what author wrote(good point to abandon your approach):

> This isn't a bad approach, since it records every purchase made by every customer. But what if you started to ask complicated questions, such as:
>
> **How many 3" Red Freens did Freens R Us order in 2002?**
>
> **What are total sales of 56" Blue Freens in the state of Texas?**
>
> **What items were sold on July 14, 2003?**

That's my opinion :)

Comment: Hey, I just thought it would get slow eventually when we keep adding invoices and the numbers get huge. Anyways, thanks for your response, I will read through those links. I'm going to check mark this because you've given me enough to make an informed decisions.